# Mimicking ::DialogBox() for a custom Win32 modal dialog

Tags: winapi, dialog, modal-dialog

I have an old school Win32 modal dialog written in C++.  The layout is constructed in code (not loaded from a resource) and displayed using a custom modal message loop like this:

```
    // Spin message loop
    window->m_modalInfo = &mi;
    while (!mi.modalFinished)
    {
        // Get a message
        MSG msg;
        GetMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0);

        // Process dialog messages first
        if (IsDialogMessage(hWnd, &msg))
            continue;

        // Dispatch other messages
        TranslateMessage(&msg);
        DispatchMessage(&msg);
    }
```

In mostly works except for a few annoyances

1. When using Common Controls 6, the underlines on shortcut mnemonics and dotted focus rectangles don't appear after hitting the alt key as per a standard dialog.  (If I hold a key while the dialog is launching they do appear).
2. When clicking on the parent window, I don't get the dialog box frame flashing like a standard dialog box.  (before running the above loop I'm disabling the owning window).

Basically I want the functionality of the standard dialog box procedure, but without loading the dialog from a resource.

To be clear, the layout can't be loaded from a resource. I could use an empty dialog template, call ::DialogBox() and setup it's contents programmatically on WM_INITDIALOG, but I'd like to understand why the above doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Use `DialogBoxIndirectParam` if you want to layout dialog box programmatically.